# module 'selenium.webdriver' has no attribute 'get'

Tags: python, selenium

i am having a bit of trouble with this - installed pip / the webdriver & changed the path of it correctly to use selenium.

my issue right now is that it opens a new tab for me but nothing happens.
please let me know what i'm doing wrong here.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from time import sleep, strftime
from random import randint

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
sleep(2)
webdriver.get('https://www.instagram.com/accounts/login/?source=auth_switcher')
sleep(3)

username = webdriver.find_element_by_name('username')
username.send_keys('(entered my username')
password = webdriver.find_element_by_name('password')
password.send_keys('entered my password')

button_login = webdriver.find_element_by_css_selector('#react-root > section > main > div > article > div > div:nth-child(1) > div > form > div:nth-child(3) > button')
button_login.click()
sleep(3)
```

my errors

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Gamer/PycharmProjects/INSTA/venv/INSTA.py", line 8, in <module>
    webdriver.get('https://www.instagram.com/accounts/login/?source=auth_switcher')
AttributeError: module 'selenium.webdriver' has no attribute 'get'
```

would appreciate any assistance.

Comment: `webdriver.get` -> `driver.get` , same elsewhere

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you have made the instance of `webdriver` as `driver` so to open a website you need to use the instance of the `webdriver` here which you can do like:

```
driver.get('https://www.instagram.com/accounts/login/?source=auth_switcher')
```

And for further operations on the page also, use `driver` instead of `webdriver`